# Empty cells constriction in GridLayout

Tags: android, android-gridlayout

I have programmatically created `GridLayout` 3x3.

I need to fill it with 5 `RadioButtons`, like this:

```
   0 1 2
 0 O   O
 1   O
 2 O   O
```

But in my app I have this:

```
   0 1 2
 0 O   
 1   O
 2     O
```

Here is the code I use to create `Buttons`:

```
Spec FieldRowParam = GridLayout.spec(FieldRow);
Spec FieldColumnParam = GridLayout.spec(FieldColumn);
GridLayout.LayoutParams Params = new GridLayout.LayoutParams(FieldRowParam, FieldColumnParam);
btnNew = new RadioButton(this); 
FieldLayout.addView(btnNew,Params);
```

Coordinates I use in `int FieldRow`  and  `int FieldColumn`:

0-0; 1-1; 2-2; 0-2; 2-0.

Buttons with 0-0 and 0-2 coordinates  merged into 1 button, 2-2 and 2-0 buttons too.

I think the problem in empty cells between buttons, but i can't solve it. Thanks for your answers!

Comment: You have to put `Space` in those "empty" cells to make it occupied. However, I reckon `GridView` suits you more in this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just add `RadioButton` in all places and set visibility `invisible` when you don't need `RadioButton`

Comment: It is an idea, but it wills make me to change all logic in my app. And here is still no answer - why 2 buttons with different cords merges in 1 button? Anyway, thanks for idea!